# Passing some of a LINQ query into an argument of a function?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code sample in C# demonstrating how I would like to parse some of a LINQ query into a function's argument.

```
public List<object> AllElements;

public object GetAll<T>(SomeLINQQuery) {

    //get some elements from AllElements where the argument is added to the query, as shown below.

}
```

And now, to give this some meaning, what I was thinking of accomplishing would be this:

```
public void test() {
    GetAll<object>(where object.ToString() == "lala");
}
```

It's kind of hard to explain. I hope this example does it well.

Comment: I like that you provide a use-case.  If there's a use case, there's usually code that can be written that makes the whole thing work :)

Comment: From your use-case, it's unclear what the returned object is for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure. You would do it like this:

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, bool> where)
{
    return list.Where(where).ToList();
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var result = GetAll(AllElements, o => o.ToString() == "lala");
```

You could even create it as an extension method:

```
public static List<T> GetAll<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> where)
{
    return list.Where(where).ToList();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var result = AllElements.GetAll(o => o.ToString() == "lala");
```

But really, in your simple example, it doesn't make any sense, because it is exactly the same as using `Where` directly:

```
var result = AllElements.Where(o => o.ToString() == "lala").ToList();
```

However, if your `GetAll` method does some more stuff, it could make sense to pass the predicate to that method.

Comment: Looks good, but I'd defer the actual execution of the query to the last possible moment by using IEnumerable<T> instead.  It's a bad practice to take concrete containers as arguments.

Comment: I was just reusing his type. I agree, that he should use `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass some sort of predicate to the method:

```
var query = GetAll(x => x.ToString() == "lala");

// ...

public IEnumerable<object> GetAll(Func<object, bool> predicate)
{
    return AllElements.Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: So should we use Func<T, bool> like daniel said or Func<object, bool>

Comment: Well, Daniel's version is more generic and flexible, but since `AllElements` is a `List<object>` then `Func<object,bool>` will suffice.